The value of the Hauptmodul at CM point
Let $J$ be a classical normalized $j$-invariant (that is, J=j-744).
Then, it is a classical result that $J(\tau)$ is an algebraic integer if $\tau$ is an imaginary quadratic number (that is, $a\tau^2+b\tau+c=0$ with $b^2-4ac<0$).
Now let $\Gamma:=N+S$ with the genus 0, where $S$ consists of the Hall divisors of $N$ ($Q\in S$ if $Q|N$ and $(Q,N/Q)=1$) and $N+S$ is defined as a subgroup of SL$_2(\mathbb{R})$ generated by $\Gamma_0(N)$ and Atkin-Lehner involutions corresponding Hall divisors in $S$. Let $J_{\Gamma}$ be the Hauptmodul.
Then I found that $J_{\Gamma}(\tau)$ is an algebraic integer if $\tau$ is an imaginary quadratic number satisfying the conditions $a\tau^2+b\tau+c=0$ with $b^2-4ac<0$ and $(a,N)=1$ (see Theorem I, I. Chen and N. Yui. Singular values of Thompson series. In Groups, difference sets, and the Monster (Columbus, OH, 1993)).
Recently, I prove that $J_{\Gamma}(\tau)$ is also an algebraic integer for an imaginary quadratic number $\tau$ when $a\equiv 0$ (mod $N$) using modular equation. Thus, when $N$ is a prime $p$, we conclude that $J_{\Gamma}(\tau)$ is an algebraic integer for any CM point $\tau$.
My question is that there is any known-result for my case (that is, $a\equiv 0$ (mod $N$)).

Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075/
